# postgres: shared_buffers vs RAM

Tags: postgresql, memory

I picked up a rule of thumb for setting up `shared_buffers` depending on `max_connetions`.

I am just not sure which of those 2 caculations was meant

1.`shared_buffers + max_connections  *  work_mem  <=  available RAM`

2.`(shared_buffers + max_connections) *  work_mem  <=  available RAM`

Comment: `shared_buffers + (max_connections  *  work_mem)  <=  available RAM` - multiplication takes precedence over addition - at least in C which is the language of PostgreSQL - mind you, I've never seen a language where it doesn't!

Comment: The second doesn't make any sense from a units/dimensions perspective, so they must have meant the first.  (Not that that necessarily makes it good advice.)

Comment: Note that this is just a rule of thumb. To be on the safe side, use `shared_buffers + 2 * max_connections  *  work_mem  <=  available RAM`.

Comment: as in `shared_buffers + (2 * max_connections * work_mem) <= available RAM`, corretct @LaurenzAlbe? ... an yes, of course it is just a rule of thumb.

Comment: Yes, Multiplication still has precedence.